# Loop inside page template not working

Tags: theme-development, page-template

I am facing a problem with the loop inside the page template. Here is the code.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Blog-Template */

get_header();

$args = [
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'posts_per_page' => 1,
];

$queryP = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($queryP->have_posts()) {
    while ( $queryP->have_posts() ) : $queryP->the_post();
        ?>
        <article>
            <?php

            the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
            the_excerpt();

            ?>
        </article>
        <?php
    endwhile;
}

get_footer();
```

If I set this page as a blog page in settings then no problem happens. But when I create a custom loop for this template it doesn't work. It shows nothing just header and footer.

Comment: You dont have  if ( $query->have_posts() ) condition before your while loop. Try to add this and then check again if it's working

Comment: you can check the code again, no query variable used

Comment: Normally loops have an `if ( $posts->have_posts() )` check so that they can display a _no posts found_ type message if there are no posts, but the code here doesn't do that, so there's no way to know if it's because it found no posts, or if it found them but didn't display them.  Also, is there a reason you discarded the main query and doubled the amount of work the database had to do, instead of modifying the main query with `pre_get_posts` so it returned what you wanted?

Comment: Also, the default post type is `post` and the default status is `publish` so you don't need to put those in your query. It also needs too do cleanup afterwards

Comment: i added if statement but still not working

Comment: Maybe try using a variable name other than `$posts` as it looks like [it's a reserved keyword](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms).

Comment: still problem persists

Comment: ' set this page as a blog page in settings' - in this case, always index.php or home.php is used, not a custom page template... check the docu https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display

Comment: I mentioned that also in question. That way it works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It solved automatically. I think the WordPress version 5.5.1 is full of bugs. Thanks, everyone for your support.

Answer (score 0):

From https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/,

> Posts Page: (if not already created) create an empty page. Give it a Title that will be used on top of your posts list. This step is mandatory as you are modifying the WordPress default setting. Any other content other than Title will no be displayed at all on this specific page.

So, When you set it as **Posts page**, Your loop is ignored.

You can set it as static front page (**Homepage**) or a normal page with custom page template.

Comment: I have to add a custom loop for the blog. If I change the loop for the blog it will change everywhere. so this doesn't solve the question